# ASP.NET MVC web app published to IIS Server missing pages - how to fix?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I do publish my web application to the real server.

After I test, everything works until I press the button to add more data.

Seems like the page name Create didn't in publish, how can I do?

I do can log-in/logout.

I can delete/ update but I cannot press the button 'Create'

Error shown:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>
> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Detailed error information:

```
Module
   IIS Web Core 

Notification
   MapRequestHandler 

Handler
   StaticFile 

Error Code
   0x80070002 

Requested URL
   http://localhost:80/Home/Create 

Physical Path
   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Home\Create 

Logon Method
   Anonymous 

Logon User
   Anonymous
```

Comment: In HomeController, do you have a Create action? And do you have the view file for the create page e.g. Create.cshtml?